Creating a new column by pasting all columns matching part of a string in R
I have a dataframe that was read in from a file which was tab separated but had within it a column which was semi-colon separated. This column contains most of my actual variables of interest however it is not sorted as some rows contain more information than others, and some rows have duplicate values. The variables of interest do however contain an identifier as pat of their string e.g. "gene eno".
For each row I would like to identify and paste together all values where there is a match for a given identifier as below:
Current dataframe:



Column A
V9_01
V9_02




CDS 1
Index123
gene "pla"


CDS 2

gene "dah"


CDS 3
gene "blah"
Location:456


CDS 4
gene "do"
gene "rah"


CDS 5
Index127
Location893



Desired dataframe:



Column A
V9_01
V9_02
Gene_Name




CDS 1
Index123
gene "pla"
gene "pla"


CDS 2

gene "dah"
gene "dah"


CDS 3
gene "blah"
Location:456
gene "blah"


CDS 4
gene "do"
gene "rah"
gene "do", gene"rah"


CDS 5
Index127
Location893
NA



I have made the current dataframe using the following code to read in the original file:
DP_GTF<-read.delim("E:/Genome_Files/GTF/DolosPig51524.gtf", sep = "\t", comment.char = "#", header = F) %>% 
  subset(V3=="CDS") %>% 
  #select(c("V9"))%>% 
  cSplit("V9",";")


I'm not sure how to get my desired dataframe but assume I need to run grep over part of the dataframe?

An approach with base R using grep, searching for gene
transform(df, Gene_Name = apply(df[,-1], 1, \(x){
                            res <- toString(grep("gene", x, value=T))
                            replace(res, res == "", NA)}), check.names=F)
  Column A     V9_01        V9_02         Gene_Name
1    CDS 1  Index123     gene pla          gene pla
2    CDS 2               gene dah          gene dah
3    CDS 3 gene blah Location:456         gene blah
4    CDS 4   gene do     gene rah gene do, gene rah
5    CDS 5  Index127  Location893              <NA>

With dplyr using c_across with rowwise
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Gene_Name = toString(grep("gene", c_across(V9_01:V9_02), value=T)),
         Gene_Name = replace(Gene_Name, Gene_Name == "", NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  `Column A` V9_01       V9_02        Gene_Name        
  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>        <chr>            
1 CDS 1      "Index123"  gene pla     gene pla         
2 CDS 2      ""          gene dah     gene dah         
3 CDS 3      "gene blah" Location:456 gene blah        
4 CDS 4      "gene do"   gene rah     gene do, gene rah
5 CDS 5      "Index127"  Location893  NA


We can Filter for "gene" in a Map, which efficiently uses the respective columns as vectors. NULL can be replaced with NA.
> d |> 
+   transform(Map(\(x, y) Filter(list(x, y), f=\(x) lapply(x, grepl, pat='gene')),
+                 V9_01, V9_02)) |> 
+   transform(gene_name=replace(gene_name, lengths(gene_name) == 0L, NA))
  Column.A     V9_01        V9_02         gene_name
1    CDS 1  Index123     gene pla          gene pla
2    CDS 2               gene dah          gene dah
3    CDS 3 gene blah Location:456         gene blah
4    CDS 4   gene do     gene rah gene do, gene rah
5    CDS 5  Index127  Location893                NA

apply, in contrast, is designed for objects of class "matrix" "array".

Data:
> dput(d)
structure(list(Column.A = c("CDS 1", "CDS 2", "CDS 3", "CDS 4", 
"CDS 5"), V9_01 = c("Index123", "", "gene blah", "gene do", "Index127"
), V9_02 = c("gene pla", "gene dah", "Location:456", "gene rah", 
"Location893")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

